# Unable to login through Jmeter due to response code 403

Tags: jmeter

I am executing the load test by going through a login using Jmeter and unfortunately, I received a response forbidden code 403. While sending the login details a security token(named in the field `_csrf`) is also sent by the server that is a random token generated at the time of login due to that my test case not passed. Here below I am sending the response HTML data in which It has stored in the input value.

I am trying it to save into the variable using Regular Expression Extractor so that I can use that variable in the login request directly instead os hard coding invalid token`(_csrf)`.

> HTML DATA

```
<body>
<!-- Used for modals to show login screen once timed out -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (window.self != window.top) {
        window.parent.location.reload();
    }
</script>

<div id="main">
    <div id="innermain" class="standalone-page x-narrow">
        <div class=" container-fluid formcontainer">
            <h2>Login</h2>
            <form id="command" action="/login" method="POST"><fieldset>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col label-input">
                            <input name="username" id="username"/>
                            <label for="username">Username</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col label-input">
                            <input type="password" name="currentPassword" id="password"/>
                            <label for="password">Password</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row actions">
                        <div class="col">
                            <input type="submit" value="Login" class="mat-btn mat-btn-floating"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            <div>
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="94sfdefa-6e8p-4a-a2-73720ffab5" />
</div></form></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

`<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="94sfdefa-6e8p-4a-a2-73720ffab5" />`

*Look for the above line in the HTML Response Data.*

> My request data look like:

[image]

Can anyone please help me out of this it would be really appreciable ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Using regular expressions for working with HTML data is not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), consider using [CSS Selector Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS_Selector_Extractor)

1. Add CSS Selector Extractor as a child of the **previous** sampler which returns the login page
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Name of created variable: anything meaningful, i.e. `token`
   - CSS Selector Expression: `input[name=_csrf]`
   - Attribute: `value`

     [image]
3. In next [`POST`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) request where you sending the credentials just use `${token}` instead of the `94sfdefa-6e8p-4a-a2-73720ffab5` hard-coded value

   [image]

See [How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Web Sites](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-csrf-protected-web-sites/) guide for more comprehensive explanation with examples.

Also don't forget to add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan, upon successful login most probably you will receive the [cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) and you will need to have it for all subsequent requests

Comment: OMG!! Thank you for this amazing solution. It worked now. Thanks a lot !! And is there any way to follow you for future references. You are just amazing. :)